# VMWare Workstation 7.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 Host NAT Connections Dropping

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nat, vmware-workstation

I hope someone can help me with this issue. We currently have VMware Workstation setup on an Ubuntu 10.04 host with NAT networking configured for the guests (b/c we don't have a router at the servers location). Now, every 10 hours or so on some of the guests the networking is dropped (not all of them, only a select few) for a couple of minutes. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

More details about the setup:

- 2 NAT networks setup (vmnet8 & vmnet9)
- 2 NIC's
- Half of the VMs on vmnet8 and the other half on vmnet9
- Running about 25 VM's
- 2 Quad Core CPU's with 40GB of memory (so processor and cpu should not be the issue)

Most of the drops occur on the vmnet9 network.

The strange thing about it is that we have another server (basically a mirror) that does not have the NAT dropping issue.

Anyone have a fix? I have been pulling my hair out trying to resolve this problem.

Thanks very much for your help!